# Custom URL(permalink) in get method for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, get-method

I had add this form in homepage of my theme

```
     <form action="" method="GET">

        <label>NAME:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
        <button>GET</button>

     </form>

<?php
  if (isset($_GET['name'])){
  $name = $_GET['name'];
  echo "hello".$name;}
?>
```

and here I am getting url at top is

```
example.com/?name=google
```

and i want custom url as

```
example.com/name/google
```

so what should i do to get custom URL by get method?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic rewrite rule. Here's the output for your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^name/([^/]*)$ /?name=$1 [L]
```

OR You might as well try a forced 301 SEO friendly redirection:

```
# 301 --- http://example.com/?name=google => http://example.com/name/google
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=google($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /name/google? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Have you added : RewriteRule ^name/([^/]*)$ /?name=$1 [L]

above RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: I have updated the answer, check it out. also try to access: http://example.com/name/google  --> see if you can view it.

Comment: So your old links are now redirected to the new friendly links or just example.com/name/google is accessible?